# Implement augmented reality in Windows Phone 8 application

Tags: windows-phone-8, augmented-reality

I am using SLARTOOLKIT to implement augmented reality in Windows Phone 8 but the source code provided in the website has some pat file.how to implement this pat file in wp8 application. I want to detect image using augmented reality

Is there any programmatic way to generate pattern file from image? Or is there any web based service which I can send to it image and response with pattern?

If possible than give me some user guide to implement augmented reality in Windows Phone using SLAR Toolkit.

Comment: Can any one know solution ?

Comment: I found few samples code on GART but are not supported in Visual studio 2012 for Windows phone.
                                                                  Also I tried this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202984%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Getting errors like: Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'sdkAugmentedRealityCS.Matrix' and 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Matrix'

And Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Matrix' to 'sdkAugmentedRealityCS.Matrix'

Please guide through this.